# How access data form internal storage in Android

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked many times, but it has not solves my confusion. 
I have stored data of my app in internal storage in text format, i can access them through [adb](/questions/tagged/adb)[shell](/questions/tagged/shell) without rooted. how it can be accessed thorough my laptop?
The same way other apps can store files in media folders etc.

Comment: "how it can be accessed thorough my laptop?" -- use `adb shell`, as you noted. "The same way other apps can store files in media folders etc." -- you appear to be confusing [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, yes I was confused with internal storage with external storage, that was a great resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "accessed through my laptop" mean access it by plugin your phone and browse through the shared media, you can't.

Android can't eject its own internal partition to give you access to it while running.
But you can store your data of the app onto the "external" storage space, then it is possible to access it.

For the documentation on how to do this, look into the [Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), explaining external storage.

Comment: Thanks @peter, I had gone through the documentation and forums but was never clear. but now i understand the concepts.